# Conditioning modified negative binomial likelihood on number of indices

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, stochastic-processes, markov-process

I am simulating a negative binomially distributed branching process (Galton-Watson process) with parameters $R$ (i.e. $\mu$) and $k$ initiated with a single event (terming 'index'). Each branching process produces $Z$ offspring in a generation, and it continues until there are no secondary events in a generation.

For each BP sequence, I then sum the number of offspring to produce a final size of the branching process, denoted $Y$, which includes the initial event and all offspring events ($Y=\sum Z$). This process is repeated $n$ times, so my data is a simple vector of $n$ integers representing the final size of each process.

I have a negative binomial probability distribution modified to relate the underlying distribution of $Z$ with distribution of total sizes, $Y$,

(1) $P(Y=y)=\frac{\Gamma(ky+y-1)}{\Gamma(ky)\Gamma(y+1)}\frac{{\frac{R_0}{k}^{y-1}}}{(1+\frac{R_0}{k})^{-ky-y+1}}$

This is reliable when all final sizes are the result of a single index. This is all pretty standard branching process stuff. However, in my data some of these final sizes are unable to be unambiguously separated, resulting in a final size of $y$ but with $n$ indexes. To account for this, I would like to condition $P(Y=y)$ on $n$.

(2) $P(Y=y|n)=\frac{\Gamma(ky+(y-n)-1)}{\Gamma(ky)\Gamma(y+1)}\frac{{\frac{R_0}{k}^{y-n}}}{(1+\frac{R_0}{k})^{-ky-(y-n)+1}}$

As shown below, the only change needed to accommodate this was to substitute the normalizing factor used in equation 1, $\frac{1}{j}$, with $\frac{n}{j}$ as the normalizing factor in equation 2. However, I am unsure if I followed through correctly with the subsequent math. I would *greatly* appreciate anyone taking on the task of verifying this change before I proceed with subsequent analysis.

---

Very briefly, the unconditioned $P(Y=y)$ in equation 1 was derived in the following way:

1. The negative binomial probability generating function (pgf) in the branching process is $G_{NB}(s)=(1+\frac{R}{k}(1-s))^{-k}$, which specifies that one event will result in $z$ offspring
2. By induction it follows that $[G_{NB, y}(s)]^y$ is the probability that $y$ events cause a total of $y-1$ offspring
3. A normalization factor of $\frac{1}{y}$is applied to the generating function to account for the fact that only certain permutations result in valid branching sequences, resulting in a generating function $\frac{1}{y}[G_{NB,y}]^y$
4. Substituting in the NB pgf yields: $G_{NB,y}(s)=\frac{1}{y}[(1+\frac{R}{k}(1-s))^{-k}]^{-ky}$, and by induction $G_{NB,y}^{(i)}(s)=\frac{\prod^{i-1}_{z=0}(ky+z)}{y!}(\frac{R}{k})^i(1+\frac{R}{k}(1-s))^{-ky-i}$
5. In this context, $P(Y=y)$ can be generally written as $P(Y=y)=\frac{1}{(y-1)!}[G_{NB,y}(s)]^{y-1}|_{s=0}$ where $[G_{NB,y}(s)]^{y-1}$ is the ($y-1)th$ derivative of $[G_{NB,y}(s)]$ evaluated at $s=0$, so substituting in the latter formula from (4) above yields $P(Y=y)=\frac{\prod^{y-2}_{z=0}(ky+z)}{y!}(\frac{R}{k})^i(1+\frac{R}{k})^{-ky-y+i}$
6. The final equation 1 substitutes the gamma functions since $\Gamma(x)$ satisfies $x=\frac{\Gamma(x+1)}{\Gamma(x)}$ and $x!=\Gamma(x+1)$

In the conditional probability, I substituted $\frac{n}{j}$ as the normalizing factor, resulting in a generating function $\frac{n}{y}[G_{NB,y}]^y$. This should be the only change needed to account for this conditioning, though I am unsure if my subsequent math is correct.

1. $G_{NB,y}(s)=\frac{n}{y}[(1+\frac{R}{k}(1-s))^{-k}]^{-ky}$
2. And by induction $G_{NB,y}^{(i)}(s)=\frac{\prod^{i-1}_{z=0}(k(y-n)+z)}{y!}(\frac{R}{k})^i(1+\frac{R}{k}(1-s))^{-k(y-n)-i}$
3. Substituting in the latter formula from (4) above yields $P(Y=y|n)=\frac{\prod^{(y-n)-1}_{z=0}(ky+z)}{y!}(\frac{R}{k})^i(1+\frac{R}{k})^{-k(y-n)-y+i}$ and substituting in the gamma function results in the above final probability (equation 2).

Any advice would be much appreciated!